# Angular not rendering <br> in my json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

I am trying to use angular which displays on the page the element from the json. Its not working. What I am trying to do is pretty straightforward. But its not working

Here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/sqxmyrcj/1/

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('store', []);

    app.controller('PortfolioController',function(){
        this.product = gem;
    });

    var gem = 
            {
        name: 'TEmp',
        aboutme: 'A Computer Science student at <br>The University Canada.<br> <br>A Software Engineer'
        };

})();
```

Comment: The fiddle is not showing your code. Is that on purpose?

Comment: fiddle shows break line fine

Comment: @KristianBarrett that is exactly the problem. I dont see anything on my webpage.

Comment: @prajmus I see it blank. can you please help out as I cant see the same on my webpage

Comment: Please check now. I posted a wrong link

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sqxmyrcj/3/

Comment: @Dylan can you post that as a answer as that works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways of managing your controller,  you were going for the `controller as` approach and the other which is more widely used by most angularians is `$scope`.

[docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController)

Basically $scope is injected into the controller and acts a the main object for that container

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.product = {
    name: ...
  };
});
...
{{product.name}}
```

[scope fiddle fix](http://jsfiddle.net/sqxmyrcj/3)

The `controller as` method allows greater flexibility but also has more prototypical complexity.

```
app.controller('Controller', function () {
  this.product = {
    name: ...
  };
});

<div ng-controller="Controller as ctrl">
   {{ctrl.product.name}}
</div>
```

Comment: adds much clarity when you have nested views/scopes when you use the controller as syntax

Answer (score 2):

All other comments / answers have some valid points. The major issue you're facing though is 1) your using an outdated Angular version ;-) and 2) you need to use the $sce service in order to create trusted HTML:

```
(function(app){
    app.controller('PortfolioController',function($sce){
        this.product = {
            name: 'TEmp',
            aboutme: $sce.trustAsHtml('A Computer Science student at <br>The University Canada.<br> <br>A Software Engineer')
        };
    });

})(angular.module('store', []));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sqxmyrcj/7/

Cheers
Gion

Answer (score 1):

There is some problems in your javascript. Mainly you should use the scope to set the variables that you want to show in your view. See this javascript and html:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sqxmyrcj/4/)

**HTML:**

```
<html ng-app="store">

    <body ng-controller="PortfolioController">
        <p ng-bind-html-unsafe='product.aboutme'></p>
    </body>

</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('store', []);

    app.controller('PortfolioController',['$scope', function($scope){
        var gem = 
            {
        name: 'TEmp',
        aboutme: 'A Computer Science student at <br>The University Canada.<br>         <br>A Software Engineer'
        };

        $scope.product = gem;

    }]);
})();
```

Comment: so whats a $scope variable?

Comment: @fscore The $scope is a variable that you inject in your controller. It is used to make the data from the controller accessible in the view.

Comment: a scope is used to assign variable a certain "scope of validity". Every view/page has it's own scope: local scope ($scope), see https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes