# Injecting <br/> tag form a Json file is not working on an Angular page

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular

I am trying to get the Line Break element working on my Angular page, injecting it form my Json file, with not luck.

I had a look to the following question: [SO similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25232983/angular-not-rendering-br-in-my-json) but I think I have got a different scenario.

My scenario:

**JSON FILE**

```
{
"boxLeft": {
        "boxLeftHeaderDesktop": "HOURS PER <br/> WEEK",
    }
}
```

**ANGULAR:**
Angular version: 1.4.9

```
<div class="header">
    {{boxLeft.boxLeftHeaderDesktop}}
</div>`
```

**RESULT - rong**

> HOURS PER `<br/>` WEEK

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED:**

1: {{locale.earnings.boxLeftHeaderDesktop | raw}} - *not working* 
2: `<br \/>` - *not working*
3: `<div class="header">
   <div [innerHTML]="boxLeft.boxLeftHeaderDesktop"></div> 
</div>` - *not working*

Please, is there any other solution which I could try to use?

**HOW I HAVE SOLVED IT:**

using: angular-sanitize.js

Comment: what you use <br/> use just <br>

Comment: Which version of angular u r using

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34936027/angular-2-how-do-you-render-html-from-a-json-response-without-displaying-the-ta

Comment: Did you look at the linked duplicate? The accepted answer is nearly identical to the now upvoted answer on this post.

Comment: @NigHamza it obviously did not work, but thank you :)

Comment: @zero298 I am testing Sachila's below answer and I'll let you know, thank you

Comment: @matt u welcome do you try use single quote  '...<br>'

Comment: @zero298 that solution did not work for me...

Comment: @zero298 so I have not been able to solve my issues, but I do agree that my questions looks quite similar to your mentioned question.
Can you please advice me how to proceed in order to block this scenario?
Shall I just delate my question, or is there any other action that I should do? Thank in advance.

Comment: @zero298 the answer to solve my question is: angular-sanitize.js
I have been able to solve it on my own, finally :)

Answer (score 0):

use the `innerHTML` to render the html tags

```
<div class="header">
   <div [innerHTML]="boxLef.boxLeftHeaderDesktop"></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: I am sorry but it did not work for me :(

Comment: I am going to updated my angular version and try your solution again

Comment: Still not working :( Do you think could I  be able to use any other solution, please.

Comment: I've finally been able to solve my issue using: angular-sanitize.js